# Select rows which have a value appear too often (based on dates specified in rows)

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2005, count, group-by

I've got a table that describes `transactions` as shown below (only relevant columns are shown)

```
ID    Date          Type     
1     2017/01/30     1      
2     2017/02/01     1
3     2017/02/02     1
4     2017/02/02     1
5     2017/02/01     2
6     2017/02/02     2
7     2017/02/25     3
8     2017/02/26     3
9     2017/02/24     3
10    2017/02/28     3
```

I'm trying to Check record's date to select rows that appear more `x` times within amount of days specified in `days` and have the same `Type`. So to give an examples where `x`=2 , `days`=2 (essentially 3 days:current day+2 following days) the results should be:

```
ID    Date          Type     
1     2017/01/30     1       
2     2017/02/01     1
3     2017/02/02     1
4     2017/02/02     1
7     2017/02/25     3
8     2017/02/26     3
9     2017/02/24     3
10    2017/02/28     3
--Basically, it's displaying records that have similar (close) dates to other records.
```

If `x` = 1, `days` = 0 (on the same day)

```
ID    Date          Type
3     2017/02/02     1
4     2017/02/02     1
```

My problem is actually quite well summarized by the first example, because records (with `ID`) 1,2 and 3 are within 3 days of each other, and records  2,3,4 are within 3 days of each other, but 1 and 4 are not. This potentially leads to 2 ranges(which means either of the 2 ranges might exclude rows).

I am thinking of using `Group by Type,[date range] having count(*)>x`, but that lead me to the problem of how to specify the `[date range]` so that I don't leave any records out in cases such as first example.

Is it possible to specify overlapping groups and have a for a single record to be grouped into in multiple groups?

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: So you want the output to be the list of transactions rather than the periods that contain an overlap?

Comment: Also, in your first example if you are looking for current day + 2 additional days as your range, would records `5`, `6` and `7` also not be returned?

Comment: I want the list of transactions (Dates are extractable with that). And yes, 5,6,7 in example I've written it certainly would be displayed. I changed the parameters and forgot to adjust examples accordingly. I'll edit in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best way to do this, but it gets the job done.  In short, it builds a table of dates from which every possible range of `@Days` number of days, returning all `transactions` that fall within each range.  The wrapping `select` then returns just the individual `transaction` values to match the output in your question.

```
declare @t table(ID int, DateValue date, TypeID int); -- Avoid reserved words as object names
insert into @t values(1 ,'2017/01/30',1),(2 ,'2017/02/01',1),(3 ,'2017/02/02',1),(4 ,'2017/02/02',1),(5 ,'2017/02/01',2),(6 ,'2017/02/02',2),(7 ,'2017/02/03',2),(8 ,'2017/02/25',3),(9 ,'2017/02/26',3),(10,'2017/02/24',3),(11,'2017/02/28',3);

-- Declare the working parameters.
declare @Days int = 2;
declare @x int = 2;

-- Build a numbers table, then use it to build a dates table.
with n(n) as (with n(n) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1))
    ,d(d) as (select top (select datediff(d,min(DateValue),max(DateValue)) + 1 from @t) dateadd(d,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,(select min(DateValue) from @t)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4,n n5,n t6)
select distinct ID
                ,DateValue
                ,TypeID
from(   -- Use the dates table to work out how many records fall into every possible range of dates.
    select d.d as RangeStart
            ,dateadd(d,@Days,d.d) as RangeEnd
            ,t.ID
            ,t.DateValue
            ,t.TypeID
            ,count(t.ID) over (partition by d.d, t.TypeID) as TransactionCount
    from d
        inner join @t t
            on(t.DateValue between d.d and dateadd(d,@Days,d))
) a
where TransactionCount >= @x    -- Then return just the transactions.
order by ID
        ,TypeID
        ,DateValue;
```

---

Output:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| ID | DateValue  | TypeID |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2017-01-30 |      1 |
|  2 | 2017-02-01 |      1 |
|  3 | 2017-02-02 |      1 |
|  4 | 2017-02-02 |      1 |
|  5 | 2017-02-01 |      2 |
|  6 | 2017-02-02 |      2 |
|  7 | 2017-02-03 |      2 |
|  8 | 2017-02-25 |      3 |
|  9 | 2017-02-26 |      3 |
| 10 | 2017-02-24 |      3 |
| 11 | 2017-02-28 |      3 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Comment: For now I ended up doing just that with a slight variation to keep the code tidier (I'll post the code). Thank you for the idea!

Comment: @Zero  Interested to see your final code!  Let me know when you post it :)

Answer (score 0):

A huge thanks to [iamdave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350987/iamdave) for all the help and continuous feedback. His answer covers everything perfectly, and comments provide some insight into topic relevant in this problem. With that said, I decided to post the final code (at the end of answer) I used and some conclusions made after working with them.

Following code is the first code I used and is **much** slower than the script [iamdave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350987/iamdave) provided.

```
SELECT *  from transactions c 
    INNER JOIN( SELECT Type,StartDate,EndDate FROM GenerateDateRange('2016-01-01 00:00' , '2016-01-05 05:00' , 4,'d') a  //all this function does is create a table with date ranges
        LEFT JOIN transactions b 
        ON b.Date>=StartDate AND b.Date<=EndDate
        GROUP BY StartDate,EndDate,Type HAVING COUNT(*)>2 ) d
    ON d.Type = c.Type AND c.Date>=d.StartDate AND c.Date<=d.EndDate
```

---

A variation of  using the method above using tally table to generate dates, which (same as example above) uses date table and transaction join (on matching dates) grouped by Type and date range as a broad filter:

```
--Variables are pretty much filters here, so I don't include them
with n(n) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
    ,d(d) as (select top (select datediff(d,@mindate,@maxdate) + 1) dateadd(d,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,(select @mindate)) from n n1, n n2, n n3, n n4, n n5, n n6)
select distinct b.*
    from(
        select d.d as RangeStart,
            dateadd(d,@Days,d.d) as RangeEnd,
            t.Type
        from d
            inner join transactions t
                on t.Date > d.d AND t.Date <= dateadd(d,@Days,d) 
                group by d.d ,dateadd(d,@Days,d),Type having COUNT(*)>@x
) a inner join transactions b on a.Type = b.Type AND b.Date>=a.RangeStart AND b.Date<=a.RangeEnd
```

---

**Best one** is an exact copy of [iamdave's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350987/iamdave), with only notable difference being an extra join to take avoid having to select fields twice (which did not impact performance in significant way)

```
with n(n) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
    ,d(d) as (select top (select datediff(d,@mindate,@maxdate) + 1) dateadd(d,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,(select @mindate)) from n n1, n n2, n n3, n n4, n n5, n n6)
select distinct b.*
    from(select --d.d as RangeStart, dateadd(d,@rangeDays,d)) as RangeEnd --commented, because not used
            t.id,
            count(t.id) over(partition by d.d, t.Type) as TransactionCount
        from d
            inner join transaction t
                on(t.Date > d.d and t.Date <= dateadd(d,@rangeDays,d)) 
) a left join transaction b on a.id = b.id
where TransactionCount > @x --and b.Type is not null
```

---

**Some comparison between the 3 scripts**

I ran some test with these queries with same parameters. The table I'm working with contains a little over 200,000+ rows, I filtered the dates to get roughly 200,000 and ran the query a couple of times to ensure it's not accidental lag.

Parameters: `Days=1; x=1` (more than 1 transaction of the same type per day)

```
 Script   avg execution time (seconds)
 1st      28s                    --with this performance, further comparison is not needed.
 2nd      7s
 3rd      4s
```

Few things to note:

- Execution time remains proportional similar with different parameter sets.
- 2nd query does *not* show `null` in `Type` (due to join type), which makes 3rd one more flexible

Comment: For your reference, using a `while` loop to generate your dates table will have much worse performance than my tally table approach, as evidenced in [this excellent write up from Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).  Your `join` logic in your final `select` will also cause problems as you are selecting from a table valued function.  Using a tally table within a `cte` per my answer will perform much better than your code here will.  Essentially, you have taken what I have done and just substituted good practice with bad.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I haven't heard of `tally tables` before, so I'll have to research a bit to figure out how to apply it (sql 2005, by the way) without having a few pages worth of code in a single query.

Comment: May I ask what your need for small scripts is?  The size of the script rarely ever has any impact on its performance and even if it did, my code above is 25 lines total - including comments and empty lines - so is hardly exhaustive.  In addition, the concepts of abstracting logic into repeatable functions that is prevalent in other software development [often has detrimental effects in SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2727/removing-function-calls-for-better-performance-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Regarding tally tables and SQL 2005, it will work as written in my answer.  A tally table is just a clever use of [Common Table Expressions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2005-common-table-expressions/), which are available in SQL 2005.  You will need to adjust for the `over` clause though.  Had you included the `sql-server-2005` tag in your question, I would not have used it.

Comment: The script size is only a preference. The query is called from client side software, and I was hoping to keep a huge chunk of reusable code out of specific queries. However, it would seem that your method significantly outperforms what I've done (and what I've tried so far).

I might end up deleting my answer, since it is beginning to seem unpractical.

Comment: As I say, the concept of abstracting re-useable code doesn't exist in SQL.  I was also wrong in my previous comment about `SQL Server 2005` and the `count() over (partition by )` function.  It is supported and will therefore work as is written.

Comment: I replaced the `with n(n) as (select n from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n(n))` with [variant that works in 2005](https://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/) and indeed the script works. I did find something that that doesn't sit right, but I'll look at it tomorow, thank you for all your help.

Comment: I would recommend utilising the new version in my answer rather than actually pulling data from disk.  There is no need to touch any tables to build a table that consists of 10 arbitrary rows.